# How many complex solutions and real solutions does the polynomial system has?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

The following polynomial equation has six variables $sb,sc,sd,cb,cc,cd$ and 7 equations
$$\begin{cases}
    &-sb-sc=0 \\
    &sb+sb*cc-sc*cb+sb*cd-sd*cb=0 \\
    &sc+sc*cb-sb*cc+sc*cd-sd*cc=0 \\
    &sd+sd*cb-sb*cd+sd*cc-sc*cd=0 \\
    &sb^2+cb^2=1 \\
     &sc^2+cc^2=1 \\
      &sd^2+cd^2=1 \\
\end{cases}$$

I am wondering how many complex solutions and real solutions does it have? Are they finite or infinite?

I tried numerical irreducible decomposition in complex space and the result shows that it has 3 dim-1 components and 5 dim-0 component.

```
Dimension 1: 3 classified components
-----------------------------------------------------
   degree 2: 3 components

Dimension 0: 5 classified components
-----------------------------------------------------
   degree 1: 5 components
```

But I have no idea about real solutions, how to determine how many real solutions are there and how to determine them?

Update on the context:

The system is derived from the following system by fixing $a=0$. In order to solve it, I transfer it to the polynomial system.
$$\begin{cases}
&sin(a-b)+sin(a-c)+sin(a-d)=0 \\
&sin(b-a)+sin(b-c)+sin(b-d)=0 \\
&sin(c-a)+sin(c-b)+sin(c-d)=0 \\
&sin(d-a)+sin(d-b)+sin(d-c)=0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: could the downvoted be explained?

Comment: Not the downvoter...this was almost certainly downvoted because the question does not meet the MSE quality standards. In particular, you should always include context in your question and what you've tried.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Thank you. I just updated and how this time would be more context-based.

Comment: The context I'd like to see is some motivation. Anyone can write down a system of lots of equations in lots of variables, and ask for the solutions – we could get an infinite number of questions that way. But would any of them be interesting? Is this one interesting? Is there something that makes this one interesting? Some reason why anyone would be interested in this particular system?

Comment: I take it, by the way, that $sb$ and $sc$ and the others are single variables, not products of two variables each.

Comment: @HJ_dynamics This looks like a system derived in order to solve another problem. What is that other problem? Maybe there is a different way to approach it, which is another way more context would help.

Comment: @dxiv Yep, I updated the original system.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, $sb,sc,sd,cb,cc,cd$ are variables. I updated my question.

Comment: The two systems are not equivalent, the first equation in the polynomial system should have been $-sb - sc - sd = 0$. If there are no additional conditions on the angles, then $(0, b, \pi, b + \pi)$ is a solution.

Comment: "I tried numerical irreducible decomposition ..."  I would like to do something similar for another system of equations. What computer algebra system and routines did you use to do this?

Comment: @PPenguin It was Bertini: https://bertini.nd.edu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Partial answer, about the real solutions*.)

Let $\,A=\cos a + i \sin a\,$ and similar for $\,B,C,D\,$, then $\,|A|=|B|=|C|=|D|=1\,$, and:

$$
\text{Im}\left(\frac{A+B+C+D}{A}\right)=\text{Im}\left(\frac{B+C+D}{A}\right)=\sin(b-a)+\sin(c-a)+\sin(d-a)=0
$$

- If $\,S = A+B+C+D \ne 0\,$ this is equivalent to $\,A\,$ being a real multiple of $\,S\,$, and the same goes for $\,B,C,D\,$, so $A = \alpha\,S$, $\;B = \beta\,S$, $\;C = \gamma\,S$, $D = \delta\,S\;$ for some $\,\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta \in \mathbb R\,$.

  Adding the equations gives $\,S = (\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta) \,S$ $\implies S=0 \;\lor\; \alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta = 1$.

  $S=0\,$ gives $\,A=\alpha\,S=0\,$ which violates $\,|A|=1\,$, otherwise $\,A = \alpha\,S$ $\implies |\alpha| \, |S| = |A| = 1$ $\implies \alpha = \pm \frac{1}{|S|}\,$. Then, the sum condition requires that $\,\pm \frac{1}{|S|}\pm \frac{1}{|S|}\pm \frac{1}{|S|}\pm \frac{1}{|S|}=1\,$ for some choice of signs. This can only happen in two cases (not counting permutations of the variables):

  - $\,\alpha=\beta=\gamma=\delta=\frac{1}{|S|}\,$ and $\,|S|=4\,$ $\implies A=B=C=D$ $\implies \color{blue}{a\equiv b\equiv c\equiv d}$ $\pmod{2\pi}\,$, which is easily verified to be a solution for any $\,a \in \mathbb R\,$;
  - $\,-\alpha=\beta=\gamma=\delta=\frac{1}{|S|}\,$ and $\,|S|=2\,$ $\implies -A=B=C=D$ $\,\implies \color{blue}{a+\pi\equiv b\equiv c\equiv d}\,$  $\pmod{2\pi}\,$, which is also easily verified to be a solution for any $\,a \in \mathbb R\,$.
- This leaves the case $\,S=0\,$, when $\,\text{Im}\left(\frac{B+C+D}{A}\right)=\text{Im}\left(\frac{-A}{A}\right)=0\,$, so the equations are satisfied automatically. What remains to be determined is the solution set of the equation $\,S=A+B+C+D=0\,$ subject to the constraint $\,|A|=|B|=|C|=|D|=1\,$.

  For that, it's enough to note that four unit vectors which add to $\,0\,$ form a rhombus when placed head-to-tail, so they must be pairwise opposite, or (again not counting permutations) $-A=-B=C=D$ $\implies \color{blue}{a+\pi\equiv b+\pi\equiv c\equiv d}\,$  $\pmod{2\pi}\,$.

Putting it $\color{blue}{\text{all}}$ together, the general solution in reals is $a\equiv b\equiv c\equiv d \pmod{\pi}$.

Comment: If $S = 0$, then $\operatorname {Im}(S/A) = 0$ but $A$ is not a multiple of $S$.

Comment: @Maxim You are right, thanks. Edited the answer to cover the case $\,S=0\,$.